# How to avoid duplicate API requests in vue 3, vuex with Axios?

Tags: vue.js, axios, vuex

How to avoid duplicate API requests in vue 3, vuex with Axios ?
I want to load API endpoint data the first time hit on the route.
Then all data come will from the cache

Comment: Give a try to Vue query or swrv.

Comment: Do manual checks `if (state.data) return` in actions. Won't prevent simultaneous requests, this needs to be additionally handled

Comment: Is it possible to share any live example code as like codesandbox.io or jsfiddle.net or any GitHub repo ?